# Deep Learning Methods for Video Classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification, pytorch, computer-vision, transformer

I'm working on a dataset with ~300 videos that last from 9 to 13-minute interviews of each subject and it has all the personality-related metadata that was collected during initial surveys. Which Deep Learning architectures are best suitable for classifying high/low personality dimensions from videos?